# CMD Batch file with FOR loop closes instantly despite having PAUSE command

Tags: git, batch-file, cmd

I have this batch file (GitRepoUpdate.bat) for running `git pull` command with `FOR` loop in the GitDev directory using Command Prompt.

```
@ECHO OFF
:: This batch runs ' git pull ' command for all repos in C:/GitDev folder.

title Git Pull Batch
ECHO Running Git pull in every folder in GitDev

FOR /D %G in (C:\GitDev\*) Do cd %G & git pull & cd ..

ECHO Batch finished its job.
PAUSE
```

I saved it as a `.bat` file and when I try to run it (even as an Administrator) it just opens and closes instantly.
Yet, when I delete the code part of the batch:

```
FOR /D %G in (C:\GitDev\*) Do cd %G & call git pull & cd ..
```

it opens correctly and shows:

```
Running Git pull in every folder in GitDev
Batch finished its job.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It may be me not knowing how it works but I guess the `PAUSE` at the end should stop the command prompt from closing...
Any ideas?

EDIT:
I forgot to add that if I paste this line:
`FOR /D %G in (C:\GitDev\*) Do cd %G & git pull & cd ..`
to the Command Prompt (at any location) it works properly and does its job.

Comment: double the `%` in the for loop i.e `FOR /D %%G in (C:\GitDev\*) Do cd %%G & call git pull & cd ..` but that being said, you'll need to reconsider all the `&` sections in the loop. rather do a parenthesized code block and run the commands in batch.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick :) What do you mean by 'parenthesized code block'?

Comment: Parenthesize the block after `do` and put each command on a new line.

Comment: Type `for /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the usage information very carefully. You will find out that you have to double the `%`-signs in a batch file. *N. B.:* Use `cd /D` rather than `cd` to also switch the drive if needed. Or consider to use [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) instead…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files need an extra % on variables for reasons I can't recall (see edit below).
Try `FOR /D %%G in (C:\GitDev\*) Do cd %%G & call git pull & cd ..` instead.
EDIT: the extra % is needed in batch files, see the `FOR` reference page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) and note the Parameters section.
There is an explanation on ss64.com about the extra % [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-percent.html) if you're interested.

Comment: You're right, it's to differentiate from parameters. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Technically incorrect. :) Each `cmd` processor consumes the first `%` when launched through batch-file. on cmdline it is fine as it is processed once because it runs a single command processor. you can test the outcome as proof by running the following scenario. create a batch file called `one.cmd` add `echo for %%i in (test) do echo %%i > two.cmd` next line add `echo for %%i in (test) do echo %%i` last line add
`call two.cmd` edit another file called `two.cmd` and add `(echo %*)>three.cmd` next line `echo %*` last line `call three.cmd` Now you can launch `one.cmd` and see the results.

Comment: Once you have completed the above, you can edit the files and update `%%i` in `one.cmd` to `%%%%i` and run it again, see the results.

Comment: Maybe it's debatable, but you sent me on a quest for knowledge and I appreciate that :) From the MS-DOS 2 manual page on `FOR`:  
 The '%%' is needed so that after batch parameter processing
is done, there is one '%' left . If only '%f' were there, the system
processor would see the '%', look at 'f', decide that '%f' was
an error (bad parameter reference) and throw out the '%f', so
that the command FOR would never see it .

Comment: Yes. The problem is with the documentation, it is not 100% clear. Some other official MS docs state differently, but running these types of tests proves otherwise. :) also keep in mind, in batch `%` is an escape for literal `%` which tells us alot.